# How to load all images I will use in one services?

Tags: angular

I am wondering, how I can load all of the images from collection of strings, for example:

```
['/picutre1.png','/picture2.png']
```

When I am navigating to a webpage that displays those images, user already has them cached? Is it enough to make a get request for those?

Comment: If a user has already requested them they will most probably be cached by the browser.

Comment: @php_nub_qq, this is the thing - they have not yet requested it.

Comment: well, request them?

Comment: http.get(url)? is that enough?

Comment: Are you talking about server programming? This makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, this should be enough, be also depends on Cache related headers.

Answer (score 0):

based on what kind of images your services return.
if your services can return base64 images i think you can store to some kind of cached like redis or memcahced.

so in every webpages that need the images you can set by unique key to bind the images.

sorry for bad english